# How can I replace image with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My view like this :

```
<li id="thumbnail-view" class="count-photo">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/thumbs/'.$photo) }}" alt="">
        <a href="javascript:" class="thumbnail-check"><span class="fa fa-check-circle"></span></a>
        <ul class="list-inline list-edit">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

My javascript like this :

```
var photo = 'flower.jpg';
var res = `<img src="{{ asset('img/thumbs/'+photo) }}" alt="">`
$('#thumbnail-view img').html(res);
```

If the javascript code executed, I want to change the image

I try like that, but it does not work

How can I do it?

Comment: use `.attr("src", "linkhere")`

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough！"{{ asset('img/thumbs/'.$photo) }}" is like a template, i think you must follow the template Convention

Comment: Just use `attr`. Its a jquery function. You can set or get any attribute of a selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the inner HTML of an image, set its src property.

```
$('#thumbnail-view img').prop("src", "{{ asset('img/thumbs/') }}"+photo);
```

Sidenote: if this is in a .js file then your template engine probably will not process the asset tag so you need to hardcode the path or grab it from elsewhere.

```
$('#thumbnail-view img').prop("src", "/assets/img/thumbs/"+photo);
```

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674975/how-can-i-unify-text-that-take-from-multiple-group-radio-button

Answer (score 5):

Simple way

```
 var photo = 'flower.jpg';
 $('#thumbnail-view img').attr('src', photo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this: 
`$('#thumbnail-view img').attr('src','path/to/photo');`